# Simple Score Counter Showing: Unction Unction

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs6

so I have a game where rotating squares (rock 1, 2, 3, and 4) are going down the screen. Every time rock 2 passes a coordinate, the score should go up by 1. The problem is. I have trouble displaying the score. Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var score = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(e:Event){

    var r1:int = Math.random() * 550;
    var r2:int = Math.random() * 550;
    var r3:int = Math.random() * 550;
    var r4:int = Math.random() * 550;


    rock1.rotation += 6;
    rock2.rotation += 6;
    rock3.rotation += 6;
    rock4.rotation += 6;
    rock1.y += 20;
    rock2.y += 20;
    rock3.y += 20;
    rock4.y += 20;
    if(rock1.y >= 430)
    {
            rock1.x = r1;

        rock1.y = -143;
    }

    if(rock2.y >= 430)
    {
        rock2.x = r2;
        score++;
    scoretext.text = score.toString;
        rock2.y = -143;
    }

    if(rock3.y >= 430)
    {
            rock3.x = r3;

        rock3.y = -143;
    }

    if(rock4.y >= 430)
    {
            rock4.x = r4;
        rock4.y = -143;
    }
}

rock1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor1)
function mor1(e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
rock2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor2)
function mor2(e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

rock3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor3)
function mor3(e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

rock4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mor4)
function mor4(e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

I have a dynamic text box, named scoretext where the score should appear. I embedded the font. But it still does not work.

After "beating" one round, where my score goes to 1. It says unction unction. (Is this just function function not being able to show?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
scoretext.text = score.toString
```

with

```
scoretext.text = score.toString()
```

`toString` is a function, and `toString()`is the invocation of the function.  That is why it is outputting the string `Function Function`.  You probably don't have capital letters embedded so it doesn't display the capital F's.

Comment: This got rid of the "unction unction". But still doesn't show my score. :\

Comment: Do you have numbers embedded in the text field?  Try `trace(score.toString())` to see that the right score is being generated.